# combine 2 coulmns as one column in sql server and showing in combobox

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

i want to combine 2 columns as one and align 2nd col combined.

Example (i want to combine company id and name as 1 column),

```
coid               coname

co1                company 1

comp2              company 2

companyid3         company 3
```

---

if i simply do select coid + '   ' + coname from mytable, then it gives me result as,

```
co1   company 1

comp2   company 2

companyid3   company 3
```

i want to align 2nd col (i.e. coname to like ),

```
co1                company 1

comp2              company 2

companyid3         company 3
```

---

My code, (i am trying following code) - But still not aligned

i am trying to get max length of coid then add accordingly. In above e.g. add only 5 spaces to 3rd record, add 10 spaces in 2nd record and add 12 spaces in 1st. But still no use may be bucause width of individual character. Anyone have have any idea to do this.

```
Dim mySql As String = "declare @len1 int " & Chr(10)
mySql = mySql & "select @len1 =  max(len(coid)) from mytable" & Chr(10)
mySql = mySql & "select coid, coid + space(@len1-len(coyid)+5) + coname as coname from mytable order by coid" & Chr(10)
Dim sqladp As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(mySql, _SqlCon.sqlCon)
```

i want to show this in combobox. User should select company from list.

Comment: You will likely need to use a fixed-width font for your combobox's dropdown list, do you realise that?

Answer (score 0):

Though I havent seen any combo box looking like that,
Find the max length of conid and pad right with ' ' for all the fields and then append the coname..

I guess better format would be to display the company name and in bracket show the conid..

company 1 (co1)
company 2 (c02)

Comment: Yes. I think we can't do that unless we use fixed width font like courier. Showing Company1 (co1) is also good idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

```
create table #t (compid varchar(10),name varchar(20))
go
insert into #t (compid ,name) 
SELECT 'Col1','Company ID -1'
union all
SELECT 'ID2','Compa -1'
union all
SELECT 'Comp3','Com ID -1'
union all
SELECT '4','Company-1'
go
select convert(char(10),compid) + SPACE(10) + convert(char(20),name) from #t
go
drop table #t
```